# Vertical divider line in a scrollable flexbox div element

Tags: css, html, overflow, flexbox

I have a vertically central adaptable scrollable flexbox element, which itself should have two columns (I solved this with two child-divs). The central flexbox should have a frame and a central divider line.

I can't get the central divider line to run all the way to the bottom of the scrollable flexbox. I tried it with a third child div element but the line only appears for the vertical extent of the flexbox.

How can I make two columns in a scrollable flexbox with a frame and central divider line running all the way to the bottom?

Thank you for your help.

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/soliman/0d0tn22x/2/

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

      <div class="leftContent"> Column 1
        With a lot of lines.
      </div>

      <div class="divider"></div>

      <div class="rightContent"> Column 2
        With fewer lines
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* use the flex model */
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin: 1em 1em 0 1em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  border: 6px double red;
}

.content > div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3%;
}

.content > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.footer {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  border-left: 6px double red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this mixed flexbox and CSS table layout. You can set the content area as a table, and the three columns as table cells, so they always be equal height.

There is one issue with the approach is - it only works properly if the content is taller than the container, otherwise the vertical line will stop in the middle. See the other approach at the bottom.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1b2fsj7/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapContent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapContent > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.leftContent,
.rightContent {
  width: 50%;
}
.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapContent">
      <div class="leftContent">
        <div style="height:500px;">Left</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="rightContent">
        <div style="height:auto;">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way would be using background image for the vertical line, set that to the center of the content container, with repeat-y, the image can be just a square dot. It works well even if the content is shorter than the container.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wyrjsta/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/oyQ4xsL.png") center top repeat-y;
  background-size: 1px;
}
.leftContent,
.rightContent {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="leftContent">
      <div style="height:500px;">left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightContent">
      <div style="height:auto;">right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The problem with tables is that they don't fill out the vertical extent of the flexbox when the content of the table is smaller than the flexbox. See:
https://jsfiddle.net/czhvhz2L/show/

Comment: What is it actually in the middle? is it always just a thin vertical line?

Comment: Yes it should just be a vertical divider line between the two columns containing content.

Comment: The only way I know is to use a background image for the middle line, updated above, hope that helps.